# Getting attributes of Keychain returns NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychain

I want to get a dictionary of attributes of Keychain, but I got an `NSArray` with 1 element of `NSDictionary`. Here's my code of getting attributes:

```
NSMutableDictionary *queryDictionary = [KeychainQueryDictionaryWithServiceAndIdentifier(serviceName, identifier) mutableCopy];
queryDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes] = (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue;
queryDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit] = (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll;

CFDictionaryRef result = nil;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryDictionary, (CFTypeRef *)&result);

if (status != errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to fetch account info with identifier \"%@\" (Error %li)", identifier, (long int)status);
    return nil;
}

id ret = (NSDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(result);
```

And here's some infomation from console

[image]

Why `ret` is an `NSArray` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit] = (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne;`

Fixed it!